# Scripting the modeling of a plane world map

Tags: modeling, scripting, mesh

[image]

I'm trying to achieve exactly the same as is described in [this blog post](https://sites.google.com/a/blendercycles.com/www/tutorials/map), except that I need a *world* map with *countries* extruded. Unfortunately, it is not provided.

I'm new to blender and I'm really astonished by the result. However, I'm a bit surprised that one has to do all this by hand, [map data being openly available](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) with [python support](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp). Wouldn't it be possible to script all this?

Comment: Note that you could also pretty easily import an [svg map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Blank_maps#SVG_format) and extrude parts of it.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14404/how-to-model-a-wireframe-globe

Comment: @gandalf3 I may be wrong but then I think I don't have access to meta data like, say, country names. My idea is to be able to iterate over object names (*ie* country name) and assign the right "raise level".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do what you want is to find a map in SVG format that has the elements you need.

Import it into Blender.

[image]

(If you don't have the Imprt as SGV menu available you need to enable the addon in the UserPreferences <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>)

[image]

The map will be a series of curves that you can then extrude at will

[image]

using the controls for extrusion on the curve tab.

[image]

The naming for the curves is inherited from the naming of the curves in the original SVG file. You might want to edit that in Inkscape or Illustrator before bringing those over to Blender, or maybe you are lucky enough to find a SVG map that has the naming already done!

Comment: Great (+1). I'll try it tomorrow. I'm still interested in a scripting option though. Thanks.