# Need help with creating a globe in Blender

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I'm a beginner, and I'm trying to create a globe like in this gif

http://pitchinteractive.com/images/projects/details/brexit-detail-gif.gif

But I don't know where & how to start, right now I only have some basic knowledge about Blender. Please show me the direction or steps to create it, I really appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/77570/how-do-i-animate-a-single-face-of-a-mesh/77580#77580

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14404/1853

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need the sphere. I suggest you start with a cube. This way you get almost evenly spaced quads all around the globe.

Add a subdivision surface modifier to the cube and crank up the view subdivision to 4. Click "apply". It should look like this:

[image: round cube]

Go into edit mode with <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Go into Mesh select mode: Vertex with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and selecting Vertex.

Select everything. Hit <kbd>A</kbd> until all vertices are orange.

Make it a true sphere. Hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>. Type <kbd>1</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Use the knife tool to cut out pices of the sphere. Start the knife tool with <kbd>K</kbd>. Click around until you are satisfied. Finish with <kbd>Space</kbd>.

[image: cutting]

Go into Mesh select mode: Face with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and selecting Face. Right click all the faces you have cut out. They are still part of the big sphere. Hit <kbd>Y</kbd> to make them separate from the sphere. Hit <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude them out from the surface.

[image: Extruding]

Comment: Thank you so much!
Also is there any good way that I can trace the world map on a sphere sir?

Comment: Add the hotkey for "To Sphere": Shift Alt S

Comment: Cegaton pointed to an extremely similar question. Maybe you can combine the two.

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16695/scripting-the-modeling-of-a-plane-world-map/16707#16707

Answer (score 0):

Go to Render Properties and for Render Engine check Cycles, for Feature Set check Experimental, and for Device check GPU.

Further down the Render Properties list look at Subdivision. You might want to limit the Max Subdivisions to about 4 or 5 until you get a feel for how much memory will be used and how that affects your machine's performance. You can always up the number for a final render.

Apply a Displacement Modifier to the Default Cube and next a Subdivision Surface Modifier. Check Adaptive Subdivision. Give the cube about 3 to 4 levels of subdivision in the viewport and it will appear spherical.

In the Material Properties section go to Settings, Surface, and opt for both Displacement and Bump.

This planet will now be ready to map images of your choice to. One from black to white to drive the displacement and a corresponding colour image.