# How to make bump with Displacement Modifier

Tags: modeling

I have a world map image and a sphere with subdivided. I tried all the setting to get that world map on that sphere clean and clear way but did not get. This is my result

[image]

What else setting are missing to get a clean world map bump effect with displacement modifier. Can i achieve it with nodes and how.  Any suggestion or help. Thanks

Comment: imho it's just that to use a detailed map to create a detailed displacement, you need a *very* detailed mesh...

Comment: @m.ardito any other method which the map can be displaced like bump with nodes can it be possible

Comment: If using Cycles then you could use the ‘experimental’ true displacement and connect the inage to the Displacement socket of the Material output node. You’ll still need a high level of subdivision - as mentioned by @m.ardito - but can produce reasonable effects without extreme subdivision as it will use the texture to generate normals as well as the actual displacement.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50440/getting-experimental-true-displacement-to-work/50442#50442 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14720/1853

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "experimental" true displacement to work](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50440/getting-experimental-true-displacement-to-work)