# Can't bevel an intricate mesh

Tags: bevel

I'm trying to make a world map around a sphere like the one on the left. The problem is that I can't bevel the edge as the more intricate curves overlap.

[image]

[image]

I've tried every way I could find on the internet to make the map (Displace Modifier as in [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14404/how-to-model-a-wireframe-globe), Bolean Modifier, using the svg only as a curve, transforming the curve into a mesh, etc.)

The one on the left is using the Bolean Modifier but even using Bevel After Bolean (returns an error) or Bolean Bevel I can't seem to bevel the map edge. Maybe the back part being only one face could be one of the problems.

The one on the right is made from a Bolean of a plane with 50x100 loopcuts and the map curve transformed into a mesh and then with the bollean applied. After that I tried to bevel the edge but as expected the faces, edges whatever overlap.

I also tried loopcut arround (have to join hundreds of vertexes 2 by 2) so I could scale the part of the sides and then bevel it "by hand" but I can't scale it uniformly.

[image]

Can anyone please help me?

I can add the project file if needed, I just don't know how :/

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried to bevel with less segments? Also, do you need the bevel to be so large? Yes maybe share just one continent/island so that we can try: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Hi!
Yes I have but to no good result :/

Here is the blender file
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6613" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6613/)

Comment: I'm afraid there's no easy way to do it without overlapping, I guess you'll have to rework manually, maybe you should first simplify the shapes with some Select Boundary Loops, then Checker Deselect, then Dissolve Vertices?

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. I'll have to google all of that as I'm pretty noob on blender ;)

Comment: I'll try an answer with screeshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using mesh (and not other methods like *Displacement* modifier or *Bump* or *Normal* Maps), I'm not sure there's any easy way to fix bevels, maybe somebody will tell. Anyway, let say you have this shape:

[image]

To simplify it, use the *Checker Deselect* tool, play with the parameters to delete as many vertices as you want.

[image]

Once you're glad extrude the mesh, then bevel.

[image]

Now you need to bring some manual corrections where the edges are overlapping.

[image]

If you need to fatten the bottom, select it and use <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>.

[image]

As I suppose your mesh is supposed to bend at the end, add some additional edge loops on the surface.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the time your spending on this! I don't think I can actually simplify my shape but hey at least I learned something new ;) I'll just skip to the fix the bevels part!

Comment: why don't you want?

Comment: I need it to have some degree of definition. is there a way to then smooth just the sides? like a selective smooth?

Comment: you can use Shading > Smooth (left panel in 2.7), add a Subdivision Surface modifier, you can also add fake 3D with Bump or Normal maps, etc... it will save you a lot of memory (and headache)

Comment: I tried that already without great results but I'll try it again. Again, thank you so much for your help! I'll let you know if everything worked!

Comment: After a lot of work using your suggestions I finally got it to a nice result. As no one got any other suggestions I believe there's actually no other way to do this so I'll just mark your answer as the correct one! Thank you again for your help!