# How to apply displacement modifier on globe with mask?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, displacement

So I have a globe, made with [this texture](http://shorturl.at/ijR69) that I am using as a mask.

I wish for the land to be extruded *outwards* slightly <s>a la this</s> [exactly like this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/14404) (see below), with the oceans either completely transparent or excised.  Wireframe too (but I can probably do that on my own).

[image: the goal]

How do I go about doing this?  Maybe I am missing something, but mine looked like a [very spikey sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_stellation_of_the_icosahedron#/media/File:Echidnahedron_with_enneagram_face.png) when I tried to do a displacement modifier.  I tried several tutorials/SO questions, and I am embarassingly more confused than when I first started.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

---

## Update #1

Right, so progress has been made!  I tried [susu's](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/92768/susu) [suggestion](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14404/how-to-model-a-wireframe-globe/14720#14720) (again) and unlike the first time it worked!

One last thing:

1. How do I increase the "height" of the displacement?  I.e. extrude "outwards" or normal to globe's origin.

   - E.g. like in the first image above (see how NE Brazil/Eastern Spain has what appears to be a ~50km vertical cliff, as it would appear to a person).
2. Given the level of detail, I would imagine that the edges need to be smoothed, possibly significantly crisp?  If so, how does one do that?

   - So complex topography, e.g. the Chesapeake Bay/coast of Norway would not look like a ball of rubber bands/M.C. Escher having a stroke.

#### Without "ocean" visible

[image: with the ocean "sphere" hidden]

#### With "ocean" visible

[image: with the ocean "sphere" visible]

#### Materials

[image: materials for each sphere]

Outliner (might be helpful to experts/hapless noobs stumbling across this in the future):

```
 - Scene
   - Camera
     - displacement globe
       - displace sphere
         - globe displacement material
       - Modifiers
         - Subdivision

     - solid globe
       - solid color sphere
         - globe solid material
       - Modifiers
         - Subdivision

     - Sun

     - wireframe globe
       - Sphere
         - globe wireframe material
       - Modifiers
         - Subdivision
         - Wireframe
```

(as you can see, 3 spheres inside each other, with `displacement` sphere extending outwards.

---

## First Attempt

#### globe

[image: Globe]

#### materials

[image: Materials]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14720/92768

Comment: I tried that before and it went horribly wrong (so wrong that I could not replicate it and I wish I'd taken screenshots).  Tried again and it worked fantastically; post has been updated to reflect this.